# Исключающий поиск и удаление файлов через cmd / bat

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

В `x` папках находятся `x` файлов, которые в наименовании имеют вид `куча_цифр_куча_цифр.wav`, рядом во всех этих же папках есть точно такие же файлы, но наименования `%%~a.converting.wav`. Каким образом по маске найти и удалить все, что не имеет в названии `*.converting.*` через `cmd`?

вот например, что-то типо такого: (одна простая строчка)

`for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "c:\records\*"') do if not "%%a"=="*.converting.wav" del /q "%%~a"`

просто не в курсе какие есть еще простые способы, не могу заставить cmd искать по маске для выполнения условия `do if not`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из командой строки в одну строчку легко вызывается набор команд для удаления. 
Например, удалить все **вложенные** файлы в каталоге **c:\folder**, не имеющие в имени фразы **.converting.**

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=/" %i in ('dir /a-D С:\folder\* /S /b^|find/i".converting." /v') do @echo del "%i" /q
```